# Get access to value that failed validation, in a replacer?

Tags: validation, laravel

When using a custom validation rule and replacer within Laravel, I am really struggling to find any documentation that would simply allow you to get the value that failed validation.

For example, I have created a file exists validator:

```
Validator::extend('view_exists', function($field,$value,$parameters) 
{
    return View::exists($value);
});
Validator::replacer('view_exists', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters)
{
    return str_replace(':filename', 'THE ENTERED VALUE', $message);
});
```

Now, when I create a rule that is:

```
$rules = array('filename' => 'required|view_exists');
$messages = array('filename.view_exists' => 'Filename \':filename\' does not exist');
```

When I enter an invalid path, such as `safsakjhdsafkljh`, I was hoping it could return

```
Filename 'safsakjhdsafkljh' does not exist
```

However the `replacer` is not able to access the value that failed the validation. I've tried outputting all parameters that are passed to the closure, including `$this` and it's no where to be seen :(

Before I resort to using `Input::get` (urgh), am I missing something completely obvious?

Thanks

Gavin

Comment: Looking for the same thing today. Using your solution below for now.

Answer (score 6):

With Laravel 5.4 you can access Validator instance in replacer callback like following:

```
Validator::replacer('view_exists', function ($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters, Validator $validator) {
    $value = array_get($validator->getData(), $attribute);

    return str_replace(':filename', $value, $message);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this (Laravel 5.2):

```
Validator::extend('my_custom_validation_rule', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {

    $validator->addReplacer('my_custom_validation_rule', function ($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) use ($value) {
        return str_replace(':value', $value, $message);
    });

    return $value == 'foo';
});
```

In translation file:

`'my_custom_validation_rule' => ':value is not correct value.'`

Comment: This is weird, won't it call the replacer twice if you've two fields using the same custom validation?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that my initial thoughts were the only way, however I would appreciate it if anyone could suggest otherwise:

My solution is:

```
Validator::extend('view_exists', function($field,$value,$parameters) 
{
    return View::exists($value);
});
Validator::replacer('view_exists', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters)
{
    return str_replace(':filename', Input::get($attribute), $message);
});
```

Not the greatest, but hey, it works...

Comment: Perfect!!! Thank you Gavin!

Answer (score 2):

Use **`getValue()`** method from `Validator` class. To do this follow the two steps:

### First

Create your own `CustomValidator` class, which extends Laravel `Illuminate\Validation\Validator` base class:

```php
Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages, $attributes)
{
    return new CustomValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages, $attributes);
});
```

Or in *service provider*:

```php
public function boot()
{
    $this->app->validator->resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages, $attributes)
    {
        return new CustomValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages, $attributes);
    });
}
```

### Second

Create `CustomValidator` class, for example, in `app/Validation/CustomValidator.php`, with replace methods:

```php
<?php namespace App\Validation;

use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

class CustomValidator extends Validator {

    /**
     * Replace all place-holders for the view_exists rule.
     *
     * @param  string  $message
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  string  $rule
     * @param  array   $parameters
     * @return string
     */
    protected function replaceViewExists($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters)
    {
        return str_replace(':value', $this->getValue($attribute), $message);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Bald said, you can use the 4th parameter on Validator::extend() method to add a custom replacer. this is good specially when you did some query on your custom validation and you want to use the query result to generate a more expressive error message.

Example:

```
Validator::extend('unique_view_filename', function($field,$value,$parameters,$validator){

    $result = View::where($field, $value)->first();

    if($result){

        $validator->addReplacer('unique_view_filename',  function ($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) use ($result) {
            return str_replace([':filename', ':id'], [$result->filename, $result->id], $message);
        });

        return false;
    }

    return true;
});
```

In your translation file:

```
'unique_view_filename' => ':filename already exists (File ID: :id).'
```

A pretty silly example but you get the basic idea.