# Laravel Array Validation Message Value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

For array validation messages, is there a way to display the value as opposed to the attribute? Doing so without using a custom validator.

Example:

```
$messages = [
   ‘*' => ':value is invalid.’
]
```

This would output something like "email@address is invalid".

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get access to value that failed validation, in a replacer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099624/get-access-to-value-that-failed-validation-in-a-replacer)

Comment: If nothing else is available I may have to go down the custom validator route. Was hoping there was something simple like :value that could be used in the messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the index for the array validation I simply iterate over the elements I'm trying to validate instead of using the * wildcard.

```
public function messages()
{
    $messages = [];
    foreach($this->emails as $key => $email) {
        $messages[$key] = $email . ' is an invalid email address.';
    }

    return $messages;
}
```

Hope this helps anyone who is having the same problem.

Answer (score 19):

In case anyone is still looking with the latest of Laravel versions, the answer is to use the `:input` parameter in  your message output:

`'between' => 'The :attribute value :input is not between :min - :max.'`

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-error-messages

Comment: also works with Laravel 9.x Validator::extend($name, $anonymousCallable, ':input is missing');. I wonder why it was not included in their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For fully custom strings you can pass custom messages as the third argument to the `Validator::make()` method. If you need only generic descriptors you can use some built place-holders such as `:attribute`, `:size`, or `:values`

For example:

```
$messages = ['required' => 'The :attribute field is required.'];

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```

`:attribute` will be replaced by the actual name of the field under validation.

More info can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-error-messages).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ya I saw that this could be done, but I was wondering if there was a :value instead o :attribute. Attribute is the key where Im looking for the value.

Comment: Looking at the docs, I don't see a place-holder defined for the value but I think that's because it's available within the class where `$messages` would normally be defined. For instance: `['required' => 'The value ' . $this->email . ' cannot be empty.'];`

Comment: I'm doing array validation, so I can access the array by using `$this->emails`, but I don't know which index is failing. How do you get the right value into the message. `$messages = [‘*' => $this->emails[$indexHere] . 'is invalid.’]`

Comment: figured out a way around it and posted an answer.